# Add custom XMP Tags

Tags: exif, xmp

I am looking for a tool or a way (.NET) to add custom XMP fields.  Also, can someone explain the purpose of needing to know if the XMP tag is a textfield, textarea or a select?

Comment: Add fields (are fields the same as tags?) to what? Are you extending a GUI, or are you manipulating files of a certain type (images, text documents)?

Comment: I'm actually trying to add custom fields to allow the user to enter let's say - 'mynewsetting' as a custom field and set the value and write it to the file meta data.

Comment: Well, the 'X' in XMP stands for *Extensible* and so it is possible. Are there any parts of the specification that you need help with?

Comment: Well I'm a little confused on how it works in order to develop it.  Just trying to understand how to take the custom field and apply it to the file.  Some example code would be nice if possible.  I really appreciate your help on this REALLY!

Comment: [IndiSnip](http://indisnip.wordpress.com/2010/09/07/storing-custom-data-into-indesign-file-xmp/) has sample code. If you want to know more about the format basics, see the [XMP specification part 1](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/xmp/pdfs/cs6/XMPSpecificationPart1.pdf); how to add your own properties is in [part 2](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/xmp/pdfs/cs6/XMPSpecificationPart2.pdf). I haven't programmed with XMP, unfortunately, but there are others on SO who know more.

Comment: Thanks Ben, this has really helped out a lot and pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XMP is written inside files as an XML packet or as a separate XML file. The XMP specification uses a subset of RDF/XML. So you could look at (RDF/)XML manipulation tools.
For embedded XPackets however, the packet length needs to be calculated and written at the start of the packet, so it may help to have a purpose built library. Adobe provides an [XMP SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/xmp.html) (C++) for that.

XMP supports several content types for fields, like Text, Number or URL. Text fields, for example, could be restricted to values from a controlled vocabulary, for which it may make sense to use a *select* or *dropdown* form element in a GUI.